# Concatenate two SQL tables for all column variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with the same columns variables, but different period.

table_1:

```
 id         period    colm1    colm2    ...    column 100
1134     2021-12-01    aa       aas               aasasq 
1126     2021-12-01    aa       aas               aasasq 
 ..         .....      ..        .                  ...
1123     2021-11-01    aa       aas               aasasq
```

table_2:

```
id         period    colm1    colm2    ...    column 100
1331     2021-10-01    a2       a12as            12asas 
1224     2021-10-01    a231     12as             a12asq 
 ..         .....      ..        .                  ...
2223     2021-10-01    a1       a12s             a14asas
```

How can I join one table on top of the other? i.e.,

```
id         period    colm1    colm2    ...    column 100
1134     2021-12-01    aa       aas               aasasq 
1126     2021-12-01    aa       aas               aasasq 
 ..         .....      ..        .                  ...
1123     2021-11-01    aa       aas               aasasq 
1331     2021-10-01    a2       a12as            12asas 
1224     2021-10-01    a231     12as             a12asq 
 ..         .....      ..        .                  ...
2223     2021-10-01    a1       a12s             a14asas
```

I think that left join does not work for me, because they are going to paste all the columns together again in each ID, I just want to concatenate them, one after the other.

I tried with

```
(SELECT * FROM table_1)
 UNION ALL 
(SELECT * FROM table_2)
```

but this took too long and finally got a 'timeout'

Comment: Use union or union all in your query

Comment: Something like this (SELECT * FROM table_2) UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM table_2)?

Comment: `UNION ALL` is the correct solution. Your performance issue should be another question, but you may be able to solve it yourself by inspecting the execution plan.

Comment: @DaleK I don't know what is execution plan

Comment: Thats something you can research.